# WooCommerce There are no payment methods available

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a custom payment gateway for woocommerce. While it displays on the admin, it is unavailable on the checkout page. See my code below

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Payment Gateway
Description: Custom payment gateway for WooCommerce.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

// Initialize the gateway
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_custom_gateway');

function init_custom_gateway() {
    if (!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) {
        return;
    }

    class WC_Custom_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
        public function __construct() {
            $this->id                 = 'custom_gateway';
            $this->method_title       = __('Custom Gateway', 'woocommerce');
            $this->method_description = __('Custom payment gateway for WooCommerce', 'woocommerce');
            $this->title              = $this->get_option('title');
            $this->has_fields         = true;

            // Load settings
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();

            // Define user set variables
            $this->title = $this->get_option('title');

            // Actions
            add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_' . $this->id, array($this, 'receipt_page'));
        }

        // Gateway Fields
        public function init_form_fields() {
            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'   => __('Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'    => 'checkbox',
                    'label'   => __('Enable Custom Gateway', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default' => 'yes',
                ),
                'title'   => array(
                    'title'       => __('Title', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __('Payment method title that the customer will see on your website.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'     => __('Custom Gateway', 'woocommerce'),
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
            );
        }

        // Payment form on checkout page
        public function payment_fields() {
            echo '<p>' . __('Custom payment information', 'woocommerce') . '</p>';
        }

        // Process the payment and return the result
        public function process_payment($order_id) {
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

              // Mark as on-hold (we're awaiting the cheque)
              $order->update_status('on-hold', __( 'Awaiting cheque payment', 'woocommerce' ));

            // Mark as processing (payment received)
            // $order->update_status('processing');

            // Reduce stock levels
            // $order->reduce_order_stock();
            wc_reduce_stock_levels( $order_id );

            // Remove cart
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();

            // Return a success redirect
            return array(
                'result'   => 'success',
                'redirect' => $this->get_return_url($order),
            );
        }

        // Receipt page
        public function receipt_page($order_id) {
            echo '<p>' . __('Thank you for your order.', 'woocommerce') . '</p>';
        }
    }

    // Register the gateway
    function add_custom_gateway($methods) {
        $methods[] = 'WC_Custom_Gateway';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_custom_gateway');
}
```

I have actived and enabled the plugin under Woocommerce setting and still does not work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySNdn.png)

My checkout page still looks like thos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UTmI.png)

What could I been doing wrong?